# Проблема с передачи массивов через preferences в Java Android

Tags: java, android, массивы, set

### Суть программы:

Таблица, в которую можно вписывать текст и менять цвет разных клеток.

### Реализация программы:

Я попытался вшить preferences для сохранения данных после перезапуска программы. Для этого я создал 2 метода: saveTable (для сохранения данных перед выходом) и loadTable (для выгрузки данных при входе). Метод saveTable я заставил запускаться с стандартным методом protected void onResume(), а метод loadTable - стаким же стандартным методом protected void onStop(). Я решил вшить loadTable в onStop потому как согласно таблице из моего учебника (Head First Android), он выполняеться в любом случае (как при запуске, так и при перезапуске или возвращении активности на первый план.

### Суть проблемы:

Почему-то переданный через preferences массив HashSet в методе `saveTable()`, который должен сохранять данные в формате `String` после преобразования из `HashSet` (Массив называеться `PutText`) в `Set` (чтобы передать через `preferences`) и обратно этот массив (Уже `GetText`) в методе `loadTable` мне говорит Android Studio, что он теперь сохраняет данные в формате `CharSequences` или в формате `Integer` Вот скриншот: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если все таки переобразовать это в `CharSequences` или в `Integer`, то клетки в программе заполняються пустотой.
В этом и заключаеться проблема.

### Полный код из `MainActivity.java` и `activity_main.xml`

---

Вот код из `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.hfad.project_n20;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class MainActivity<GT> extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Name_Enter;
    Button Num_1;
    Button Num_2;
    Button Num_3;
    Button Num_A;
    Button Num_B;
    Button Num_C;
    Button A1;
    Button A2;
    Button A3;
    Button B1;
    Button B2;
    Button B3;
    Button C1;
    Button C2;
    Button C3;
    RadioButton Color_Red;
    RadioButton Color_Blue;
    RadioButton Color_Green;

    String a1_text = "";
    String a2_text = "";
    String a3_text = "";
    String b1_text = "";
    String b2_text = "";
    String b3_text = "";
    String c1_text = "";
    String c2_text = "";
    String c3_text = "";

    TextView loglist;

    final String SAVED_TEXT = "saved_text";
    final String SAVED_COLOR = "saved_color";
    final String RED = "RED";
    final String BLUE = "BLUE";
    final String GREEN = "GREEN";
    final String NOTHING = "NOTHING";
    SharedPreferences sPrefColorSave;
    SharedPreferences sPrefTextSave;
    SharedPreferences sPrefColorLoad;
    SharedPreferences sPrefTextLoad;

    HashSet<String> PutText = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> PutColor = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> GetText = new HashSet<>();
    HashSet<String> GetColor = new HashSet<>();

    String GT [] = new String [10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Name_Enter = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Name_Enter);

        Num_1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_1);
        Num_2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_2);
        Num_3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_3);
        Num_A = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_A);
        Num_B = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_B);
        Num_C = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Num_C);

        A1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.A1);
        A2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.A2);
        A3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.A3);
        B1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B1);
        B2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B2);
        B3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.B3);
        C1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.C1);
        C2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.C2);
        C3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.C3);

        Color_Red = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Color_Red);
        Color_Blue = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Color_Blue);
        Color_Green = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.Color_Green);

        loglist = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tV);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        loadTable(); //При перезапуске выполняеться заполнение клеток текстом
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        saveTable(); //текст из клеток сохраняеться при выходе из программы
    }

    public void OnClick(View view){
        switch (view.getId()){ //Это чтобы красить(пока не реализовано) и вставлять текст в клетки
            case R.id.A1:
                if(Color_Red.isChecked()){
                    A1.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a1_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else if(Color_Blue.isChecked()){
                    A1.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a1_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else if(Color_Green.isChecked()){
                    A1.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a1_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else{
                    A1.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a1_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }

                break;

            case R.id.A2:
                if(Color_Red.isChecked()){
                    A2.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a2_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else if(Color_Blue.isChecked()){
                    A2.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a2_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else if(Color_Green.isChecked()){
                    A2.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a2_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }
                else{
                    A2.setText(Name_Enter.getText());
                    a2_text = String.valueOf(Name_Enter.getText());
                }

                break;

        }
    }

    void saveTable() {
        if(a1_text == ""){
            a1_text = "-----";
            PutText.add(a1_text); //Если эту клетку не заполнили за время выполнения - сохраняеться стандартное значение
        }
        else{
            PutText.add(a1_text);
        }

        if(a2_text == ""){
            a2_text = "-----";
            PutText.add(a2_text);
        }
        else{
            PutText.add(a2_text);
        }

        sPrefTextLoad = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor edText = sPrefTextLoad.edit();
        edText.putStringSet(SAVED_TEXT, PutText);
        edText.commit(); //просто сохранение данных текста
    }

    void loadTable(){
        sPrefTextLoad = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        GetText = (HashSet<String>) sPrefTextLoad.getStringSet(SAVED_TEXT, GetText);
        Iterator iterator = GetText.iterator(); //создание итератора
        A1.setText(iterator.next()); //а вот тут уже ошибка
    }

}
```

---

Вот код из `activity_main.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
            android:layout_width="111dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Color_Red"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Red" />
    
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Color_Green"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Green" />
    
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/Color_Blue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Blue" />
        </RadioGroup>
    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Name_Enter"
            android:layout_width="574dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.312"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioGroup"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/B2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/B2" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/A2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/A2" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/C1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/C2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/C2" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/A3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/A3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/C3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/B3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/C2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/C3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Num_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Num_3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Num_2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Num_2" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/B2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/B3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/B3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/A2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnClick"
            android:text="-----"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/A3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/A3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_2"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Num_3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Num_3" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_3"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="164dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="3"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/Name_Enter"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Name_Enter" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_C"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="C"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/C1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/B1" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_A"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="A"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/A1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/A1" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Num_B"
            android:layout_width="57dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="B"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/B1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/B1" />
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tV"
            android:layout_width="447dp"
            android:layout_height="157dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="133dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="152dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:text="TextView"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C1"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

Надеюсь на вашу помощь

Comment: Первое(ответ на Ваш вопрос). Просто обозначьте тип `Iterator<String>`. Второе. `set` не подходит для Ваших нужд - он не гарантирует сохранность порядка элементов, что Вам важно. Третье. НИКОГДА НЕ НАЗЫВАЙТЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ С БОЛЬШОЙ БУКВЫ. Серьезно. У меня глаза сейчас кровью плачут. Я голосую за закрытие Вашего вопроса, так как его формулировка никак не связана с реальным источником проблемы, а сама проблема состоит в элементарной опечатке, которую ПОДСВЕЧИВАЕТ СТУДИЯ

Comment: Дам ещë совет. Всегда обращайте внимания на код, подсвеченный бежевым. Вы там ещë строки неправильно сравниваете.